# Differences between mobile and console versions of Terraria?

Tags: terraria

i know a lot of differences between pc and console version but i dont know any difference between mobile and xbox360/ps3. is there any difference?

Comment: The Mobile and Console version are quite similar. I don't know about any major differences though.

Comment: i know one difference: on mobile version there is not an hardmode but console have hardmode

Comment: ITS NO DUPLICATE. AFTER MY QUESTION SOMEONE EDITED QUESTION: Difference between PC and console version and it became Different between PC console and  mobile.     EVIL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console version has hardmode, and a number of weapons, armors, and enemies not present on the mobile version.

http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Console_version

http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mobile_version